# Function works with onClick but not using an eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener

I've created a function to toggle a class on and off an element with a certain id. It works like this with onclick in the html:

HTML:

```
<a href="#menu" class="menutoggle" onclick="toggle(className);">
  <h2id="menubutton">Menu</h2>
</a>
<ul id="menutoggle" class="hidden">
```

JavaScript:

```
var toggle = function (className) {
  var toggleclass = document.getElementById(className); // identify element to change
    if (toggleclass.className === "hidden") { // if class = hidden
        toggleclass.className = "shown"; // change to shown
    }
    else { //if not hidden
        toggleclass.className = "hidden"; // change to hidden
    }
};
```

However if I try to use the function with an eventlistner, I'm out of luck:

HTML:

```
<a href="#menu" class="menutoggle">
  <h2 id="menubutton">Menu</h2>
</a>
<ul id="menutoggle" class="hidden">
```

JavaScript:

```
var toggle = function (className) {
    var toggleclass = document.getElementById(className); // identify element to change
    if (toggleclass.className === "hidden") { // if class = hidden
        toggleclass.className = "shown"; // change to shown
    }
    else { //if not hidden
        toggleclass.className = "hidden"; // change to hidden
    }
};

var tog = document.getElementsByClassName("menutoggle")[0];
tog.addEventListener("click", toggle(className), false);
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of `addEventListener` needs to be a *function*.

You aren't passing it a function. You are calling the `toggle` function and passing its return value. Since `toggle` doesn't have a `return` statement, that value is `undefined`.

If you want to call `toggle` with a specific argument, you can [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
tog.addEventListener(
    "click", 
    toggle.bind(this, className),
    false);
```

Replace `this` with whatever you want the value of `this` to be inside the function (since you don't use `this` there, it doesn't matter what that is).

Make sure you define `className`, you don't anywhere if the code in the question.

If you need to support IE8 or earlier, then you can create a new function instead of using `bind`:

```
tog.addEventListener(
    "click", 
    function () { toggle(className) },
    false);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not defining the className because I want the function to get the classname from the element its targeting. If that makes sense. So I can reuse the function multiple places.